# Submitting a file attachment from a HTML form to an external API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, ejs

I'm currently creating a web form that submits data from the form to an external API. The API is for a system we use to manage processes called Fusion Lifecycle. So far, I've managed to get all the fields from the form to submit to the api successfully. The problem I'm having is with file uploads, I've written some code using the express and request modules, but it's not quite working the way it should.

I've been using this documentation to try and get this working: http://help.autodesk.com/view/PLM/ENU/?guid=GUID-F31EF246-A5EA-4892-B188-AA3F11DE4DBB but as there isn't a full Node JS example, I'm struggling a bit.

This is the code I am trying to run in my app.js file

```
const request       = require('request');
var express         = require('express');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var fs              = require('file-system')

app.post('/submit-form', (req, res) => {

const file = req.body.file;

var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://mytenant.autodeskplm360.net/api/rest/v1/workspaces/{workspaceid}/items/' + dmsid + '/attachments',
            headers:
            {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                'content-disposition': '*; filename=' + file,
                'Cookie': cookie
            },
            encoding: null,
            body: fs.createReadStream(file),
            json: true,
        };

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);

            console.log(body);
        });
});
```

This is the input field in my index.ejs file

```
<label for="file"><strong>Upload files: </strong></label>
<input type="file" name="file" multiple>
```

This is all I get outputted in the console, but I am suppose to get a response back as illustrated in the documentation:

```
<Buffer 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 22 55 54 46 2d 38 22 20 73 74 61 6e 64 61 6c 6f 6e 65 3d 22 79 ... >
```

Comment: Check your headers.. `accept` and `content-type` need proper spelling. Look up the request docs on how to make requests w. cookies.

Comment: I've used these headers for other requests in the past and it's always worked, why would they stop working now?